# mysqli_real_escape_string foreach function db_array_update

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

Someone wrote a PHP program many times ago for me, and now I got this error when I run the code :

> `mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in....

I cannot fix this here is the code :

```
function db_array_update($table, $a, $where) 
{    
    $q = "update $table set ";
    $b = NULL;  

    foreach($a as $key => $value)   
    {   
        if (is_int($key))
            continue;   

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", MYSQLUSER , MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
        $b[] = "$key='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value)."'";        
    }

    $q .= implode(",", $b);
    $q .= " where ".$where;

    db_query($q);

}
```

and I use it like this :

```
db_array_update("all_data",array('last_fetched' =>date("Y/m/d H:i:s"),'name'=>$name, 'creation'=>$creat, 'expiration' =>$expire,"id=".$res['id']);
```

Can someone help me how should I fix this ?
Tried many things but not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's being passed into your function as `$a` must have one or more array values that are arrays themselves. You will get this error if `$value` is an array, ie. you have a multi-dimensional array instead of simple key/string pairs.

Do `var_dump($a)` inside your function to see which one of your array values is an array. Also, you have some goofs in the data you pass in:

```
db_array_update("all_data",array(
    'last_fetched' => date("Y/m/d H:i:s"),
    'name'=>$name,  // May be an array?
    'creation'=>$creat,  // May be an array?
    'expiration' =>$expire, // May be an array?
    ), // Need this closing ) to end the array.
    "id=".$res['id'] // This one should be outside the array!
    );
```

Also you need to close the array before the `'id='` bit that you're passing in for the `$where` condition, you have unclosed parentheses there.

...Really though, your code is full of funnies outside this issue. Study the answers here. If this is a representative specimen of the code, someone should rewrite your database functionality.

Comment: Could you please tell me why the code is full of funnies ? for what ?

Comment: I notice now that the array you pass in also had unclosed parentheses, and your spelled-out `"id=".$res['id']` was included in the array of fields for update. That would cause problems. If you had that as a part of the array, it would result in the last pair of your update clause becoming: `0 = 'id=123'` (or whatever your `$res['id']` is). Your function would also probably give you an error of `$where` not being defined, and your SQL query would fail because it'd end with `where` without anything to follow.

Comment: Among the "funnies" are these. 1. You establish the MySQL connection at each loop. You should at the very least just have that in the beginning of the function, and you'd probably want to just establish the connection once in your code, and keep re-using that connection (e.g. by passing the connection variable in function parameters or declaring a global, if you're not into re-factoring this into a proper class, where you could just have the link stored in `$this->sql` or something.)

Comment: 2. Your function should check that there's a well-formed ID for the `WHERE` clause (ie. as `id=integer`); otherwise you may end up even overwriting the entire table with the same values. For example, pass the `$where` as an array, `array('id' => $res['id'])`, and in your function, check e.g. `if (!is_array($where) || !is_int( current($where)) { die('Doing this would be bad.'); }`. If ID is the only reference field, you can hard-code it into your function and pass an integer for `$where` and check to match. If there are multiple `WHERE` fields, validate the key/val pair(s) against them.

Comment: ^ and of course, using prepared statements would be safer. 3. You may want to use a standard MySQL datetime (or timestamp) string and column type, instead of storing a non-standard date string. 4. Your update function returns no feedback to the system on whether `db_query()` was successful or not, you should be checking for fails to ensure the integrity of your data and avoid possibly lost transactions. 5. You define `$b` as NULL, while you should probably be defining it as an `array()` instead, since you append to it. Etc. In short, I would nuke this code from space and rewrite it.

Comment: P.S. Judging by the skill that went into this function, you may have any number of data integrity and security issues elsewhere in your code that make you subject to corrupted data, SQL injections and whatnot. It's not the work of an experienced programmer. I'd recommend to get all your code either security-audited or rewritten altogether. I'd probably rewrite the code faster than it'd take to audit it and make corrections. :P

Comment: I use that non-standard date string because I set a time zone before in the code to post the date in my time zone in the table... I checked everything and none of them is array but still getting one "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string" error when I run the code...

Comment: Surely one can also have the time in one's own timezone and in a standard format fit for a MySQL datetime field. Anyway, that's the least of the issues here. So what does `var_dump($a)` produce if you put it in the beginning of your function?

Comment: I think the problem solved, I will study PHP more and will use your recommendations to write new code :).

Comment: about the mysql connection, could you please give me a piece of code or something like that so I can understand that and can rewrite the code... because I have no idea how to do that. I'm PHP beginner... :)

Comment: To keep things simple, just move the `$con` line outside the `foreach` loop, because you only need to establish the database connection once. The code on that line is fine. Otherwise, move it somewhere to the file where you call this function from, and pass it as a function argument; or place it into your main file (`index.php` or whatever other file that's parsed on all page loads) before any database functions are called, and use `global $con` in the beginning of the function. (Do likewise with any other functions, if you have other database functions that keep re-connecting needlessly.)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the mysqli is done wrong. The whole benefit of mysqli has been reduced to about zero. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php for examples.

To correct a part of the code:

- Connection was opened many times: Really inefficient.
- escape is not required when adding data into the database the correct way: No use of variable binding=> Very weak protection against SQL injection.

The code after these possible corrections:

```
function db_array_update($table, $a, $where) 
{    
$q = "update $table set";
$b = NULL; 
$c=null; 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", MYSQLUSER , MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
foreach($a as $key => $value)   
{   
    if (is_int($key))
        continue;   

    $b[]="$key=?";
}

$q .= implode(",", $b);
$q .= " where ".$where;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
foreach($a as $key => $value)   
{   
    if (is_int($key))
        continue;   
    $stmt->bind_param($key, $value);
}


$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

}
```

This is still not compliant:

- $where is an unknown string, should be with parameter binding.
- $table is assumed an internal value, but should just be a direct table name to prevent any abuse there.

Comment: Good basic tuning. If `$table` is not coming from user input, I don't see why it needs to be hard-coded there, if it is defined internally elsewhere in the code. After all, if someone can execute arbitrary code on your server, you have more trouble than this function. For the `foreach` loops, you probably don't want to skip adding and binding the integers. :)

Comment: @MarkusAO Yes, probably have to remove the if statements. The original code is not really transparent on that point.

Comment: The original code is being "economical" in not escaping integers, good optimization there . :D It still adds them inside quotes huh. How many wrongs in OP's code, did you lose count yet?

Comment: @MarkusAO I know that this code will not produce a lot of good for sure :)